# i have a type error #1009 on my coding and i don't know how to locate it

Tags: actionscript-3, air, jquery-animate, adobe, game-development

I am creating a quiz game but when I test run my game, this error pops up

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
at issitokay_fla::MainTimeline/frame6()[issitokay_fla.MainTimeline::frame6:1]
at flash.display::MovieClip/gotoAndStop()
at Function/<anonymous>()[issitokay_fla.MainTimeline::frame5:8]
```

for context, this is my coding on frame 6

```
okay2_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, right_ans3('1.4'));
notOkay2_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, wrong_ans3('1.4'));
score_cnt.text=arnab.toString();

//quiz func
function right_ans3(next_question:String):Function{
return function (e:MouseEvent): void{
arnab++;
gotoAndStop(next_question);     
}
}

function wrong_ans3(next_question:String):Function{
return function(e:MouseEvent): void {
    gotoAndStop(next_question);
}
}
```

and this is my coding on frame 5

```
okay2_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, right_ans2('1.3'));
notOkay2_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, wrong_ans2('1.3'));
score_cnt.text=arnab.toString();

//quiz func
function right_ans2(next_question:String):Function{
return function (e:MouseEvent): void{
arnab++;
gotoAndStop(next_question);     
}
}

function wrong_ans2(next_question:String):Function{
return function(e:MouseEvent): void {
    gotoAndStop(next_question);
}
}
```

they are just basically the same. I tried to do the same code as above but with different functions, but it works well. I tried to search for a solution, but I do not understand how it works. can anyone lighten me?

Comment: Check if your `okay2_btn` exists and is the same entity on frames 5 and 6. Invalidating that pointer is what causes your 1009 right now. Also there is a lost listener from previous call of a generated function that does not stop acting when you change frames between 5 and 6 (or rather 4 and 5), and running its code could also result in a 1009. Better plan your code to have complete control of events, or else you'll get hardly traceable bugs and errors.

Comment: @Vesper they are from the same instance button. do I have to duplicate the button to fix it? also, how to create a function that will stop running when changing frames?

Comment: @Chacha Why keep moving the Stage to different frames? Put all code and assets (buttons, textfields, etc) on frame 1. Also put an MClip with your question contents on its own frames (an MClip has a timeline just like the Stage). When a button is clicked, you move the questions MC itself to another frame (not move Stage itself) then you won't get these reference errors, because all code is on frame 1 and is talking to buttons/text/MClips that also all exist on frame1.